# How to filter the dashboard based on logged in user , while embedding the QuickSight dashboard in an external application having thousand of users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I want the Amazon QuickSight dashboard to get filtered based on logged in users while embedding it in an external application.

The scenario is similar to YouTube dashboard, where the content owners can see the insights of their uploaded video (like count of views , likes , traffic etc.) only , where the dashboard was filtered based on the author.

Here I have dashboard developed in AWS QuickSight, but while embedding   the user should see insights about his/her own  videos.

Comment: You should use row level security for that. Restrict dataset by a row level security dataset.

Comment: Thank you , Its a good option. But in my scenario I have thousands of users, so if I go by row level security I might need to register my users with QuickSight which may not be a viable option considering the pricing for each session. Is there an alternate approach?

Comment: Oh, I see, your dashboard is public then? In which case I found this official QuickSight YouTube video workshop to be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0xmILp225s